# Swift - What Type is '()'?

Tags: swift, swift3

I tested some code to understand completion handlers, and I found that there are types such as `()->()` and `()`.

I know `()->()` means "no parameters and no return value"; but what type is `()`?

If I define a function like this:

```
func sayHello(){
  print("hello")
}
```

and then check the type:

```
type(of: sayHello) // ()->()
type(of: sayHello()) // ()
```

Is "*function execution*" (`()`), a type?

Comment: Hint - change the return type of `sayHello` and see the change in results.

Comment: () in this case is the same as Void

Answer (score 3):

What you are really asking is why does `type(of: sayHello())` result in `()`.

Start by thinking about what `sayHello()` does. It actually calls the function. So `type(of:)` is telling you the type of the result of that call. Since the return type of `sayHello` is `Void`, the type is `()`. It's basically the second `()` of `() -> ()` seen in the first call to `type(of:)`.

If you change `sayHello` to have a return type of `Int` instead of `Void`, then the 2nd `type(of:)` returns `Int` instead of `()`. And the 1st `type(of:)` would change from `() -> ()` to `() -> Int`.

tl;dr - `()` represents `Void`. The return type of calling `sayHello()`.

Comment: Oh...Void..!! I just trapped in myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
typealias Void = ()
```

> The return type of functions that don't explicitly specify a return
>   type; an empty tuple (i.e., ()).
>
> When declaring a function or method, you don't need to specify a
>   return type if no value will be returned. However, **the type of a
>   function, method, or closure always includes a return type, which is
>   Void if otherwise unspecified**.
>
> Use Void or an empty tuple as the return type when declaring a
>   closure, function, or method that doesn't return a value.